# GCP - Error creating Queue: googleapi: Error 400: The queue cannot be created because a queue with this name existed too recently

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I started to work with Cloud Tasks, I am performing some tests so I created and deleted Cloud Tasks queues from the GCP console a couple of times.
Every time I delete a queue and try to recreate it with the same name I get this error:

- Error creating Queue: googleapi: Error 400: The queue cannot be created because a queue with this name existed too recently.

So, to create a new queue, I need to change the name every time.
The error tells something about the "queue existed too recently" but I created the first queue more than a week ago and I keep getting the same error.
I am quite confused about this error and it feels quite like a bug to me.
I am wondering if the queue have actually been deleted or if I am collecting a bunch of unreachable queues into my project.

Is there someone else who got the same error?
The fact that after a week I still get this error is the expected behavior?
How much time do I need to wait until the namespace for a GCP Cloud Tasks queue becomes available again (if ever)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

According to [**Official Documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/deleting-appengine-queues-and-tasks#deleting_queues), after you delete the queue you must wait **7 days** before recreating with the same name.

Please check if the queue has been deleted over more than 7 days. Wait some more days in order to re-use it.

If still you are getting the same error, please create a [bug request in **Public Issue Tracker**](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to be investigated futher.

Comment: 7 days is a crazy wait. I have created a feature request. If you are facing the same issue you and come across this comment, please upvote the request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187101566

Comment: It says issue does not exist.

Comment: 7 days is really crazy. While using terraform to delete and recreate the queue. Now I will be waiting 7 days or creating queue with a new name and then updating cloud functions to take this new name. :D

Comment: 7 days is madness.  Who thought that was a good idea?

Comment: I deleted the queue thinking I was just deleting the contents of the queue so I can fix something.  Now I need to wait 7 days before I can continue developing?  This is such a stupid thing.  Anyone find a workaround?  Thanks!

Comment: There's another feature request in the tracker for this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/263947953

Answer (score 2):

September 2023 and google told me that I've to wait 7 days or create queues with different name.